# Grammar of "so long as S+V, S is otherwise [adjective]"

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-usage

> **So long as** the receiving market is financially open and deep enough,
>   which many emerging countries now are, that money **is otherwise pretty
>   indifferent to** the merits of the economies it is parked in.

Source: Economist

I guess it means as long as the receiving market is financially open and deep enough, investors don't care much about the specific nations or markets in which they invest their money. 
(If the receiving market is not financially open and deep enough, their money is going to be different to the merits of the economics it is parked in)

I looked up the word [***otherwise***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/otherwise) in Oxford Online dictionary.

> In circumstances different from those present or considered; or else

The first meaning of the dictionary seems to mean *otherwise* in the quote. Yet, I'm not sure how it is grammatically correct. Is it grammatically correct to use *otherwise* in the context?

Comment: I have just edited your question. Please take a look. You should not use the adjective *different* in the question. Try to find an alternative word or phrase and see if there is any more room for improvement in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using "so long as" makes your example strictly ambiguous between an ordinary variable comparison (comparing 'how long the receiving market is financially open and deep enough’ with ‘how long the money is indifferent to the merits of the economies’) and one where "so long as" has lost its comparative meaning and has been reanalysed as a compound idiomatic preposition meaning "provided" ("Provided the receiving market is financially open and deep enough … , the money is indifferent to the merits of the economies it’s parked in".  I think the second interpretation is probably the salient one here.

Regarding "otherwise", its use in your example is fine. It’s an adverb of condition modifying the adjective phrase "pretty indifferent", with a meaning akin to "in other respects".